# How to Keep Video and Audio in Sync When Ripping a DVD?

Tags: video, audio, sync, ripping

I have been using the freeware version of the WinX DVD Ripper (http://www.winxdvd.com/dvd-ripper/) to rip some DVDs. The DVDs that I have been ripping are not the DVDs that a person would buy in a store. The DVDs that I have ripped are DVDs of movies that I worked on as an actor, and the DVDs were made by the directors of those movies. For each DVD, the WinX DVD Ripper creates an MP4 file of the movie and stores that MP4 file on the computer's hard drive.

Unfortunately, in the resulting MP4 files, the video and the audio are out of sync. The video is ahead of the audio.

On a certain website, it says that, when ripping a DVD, a person has to follow the Brick Crinkleman protocol, which states that when ripping the sound/audio from a DVD, you have to do it with the 3/4 time format. (http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091123071551AAZ3S7G)

So, who is Brick Crinkleman, and what is the 3/4 time format? And how do I implement this 3/4 time format on the WinX DVD Ripper? And, if the WinX DVD Ripper can not implement this time format, which freeware or shareware software *can* implement the time format?

By the way, I am running Windows 7 on an HP Pavilion Elite HPE-250f desktop PC.

Thank you very much for any information and help.

Comment: You can use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) to manually adjust the audio/video sync on playback.  [See here.](http://lifehacker.com/5910943/fix-out+of+sync-audio-in-vlc-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)  It's not ideal, but in a pinch it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about all of that and hit up [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/). It's free, and It Just Works (TM).

> Handbrake is an open source,
>   GPL-licensed, multiplatform,
>   multithreaded video transcoder,
>   available for Mac OS X, Linux and
>   Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  I tried using the trial version of Aimersoft DVD ripper to convert a DVD to the WMV format and the audio had a half second to second lag.  Handbrake worked great, only downside is you can only convert to MP4 or MKV format.